# Set full span for GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have to create a heterogeneous `RecyclerView`. The default number of columns is 2, but some items require the full width. I have it while using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        FeedItems currentItem = getItem(position);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM_TYPE_HEADER:
                final HeaderItem headerItem = currentItem.getHeaderItem();
                layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        }
    }
```

How do I do the same thing for GridLayoutManager, where I can easily switch the spans based of different view types?

Answer (score 10):

There is a method [`void setSpanSizeLookup (GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup spanSizeLookup)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanSizeLookup(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)). Use it like this:

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                case 1:
                    return 1;
                case 2:
                    return 2;
                default:
                    return -1;
            }
        }
    });

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: this has to be done before setting the adapter to recyclerView or after?

Comment: Generally, setting `LayoutManager` should be made before setting `RecyclerView.Adapter`.